# How can I rename my a.exe file in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I have a `main.cpp` file, when I build it by using `task.json`, it genarates an `a.exe` file. How can I change the name of that `exe` file to something else like `main.exe` when I build the `cpp` file?

Comment: The VS compiler (`cl.exe`) option specifying the executable output is `/Fe`  (you can specify object file locations with `/Fo`) or hack the `task.json` file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`a.exe` is default output name of gcc compiler. To choose different name, in `task.json` use argument `"-o"`. Example:

```
 "args": [
            "-g",
            "main.cpp",
            "-o",
            "YourProgName"
        ]
```